# Android TTS Using alarm manager

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I'm trying to get Android's TTS to run every one hour to get the clock time in voice .I have tried but its not workiing .I have no idea why it isn't working . Can any one tell me the step to achieve my idea. Thanks in advance

Comment: It would be helpful, to show us what you have tried so far / what kind of errors you got?

Comment: what you tried till now ? why alarm manager is not working. Can you post your code